# Prisma fails on Postgres query with findMany

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma, prisma2

I have the following query in Prisma that basically returns all users where campaign id is one from the array I provide and they are added to the system within the defined time range. Also I have another entity Click for each user that should be included in the response.

```
  const users = await this.prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
      campaign: {
        in: [
          ...campaigns.map((campaign) => campaign.id),
          ...campaigns.map((campaign) => campaign.name),
        ],
      },
      createdAt: {
        gte: dateRange.since,
        lt: dateRange.until,
      },
    },
    include: {
      clicks: true,
    },
  });
```

The problem is this query runs fine in localhost where I don't have much data, but in the production database there are nearly 500.000 users and 250.000 clicks in total, so I am not sure if that is the root case but the query fails with the following exception:

```
Error: 
Invalid `this.prisma.user.findMany()` invocation in
/usr/src/app/dist/xyx/xyx.service.js:135:58

  132 }
  133 async getUsers(campaigns, dateRange) {
  134     try {
→ 135         const users = await this.prisma.user.findMany(
  Can't reach database server at `xyz`:`25060`

Please make sure your database server is running at `xyz`:`25060`.
```

Prisma error code is `P1001`.

`xyz` replaced for obvious reasons in the paths and connection string to the DB.

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely fishy if it works locally but not in prod. Just to be sure, do other DB queries work in prod or do maybe all Prisma queries fail?

Comment: Everything else works, it's just this huge query that fails... I have an idea how to refactor this but I keep it as last resort unless absolutely necessary.
What is even more fishy is that the query succeeds if the 'gte' and 'lt' range is just one day, it fails only when you put a range of more than 1 day

Comment: Got it. I work at Prisma btw and this is most likely a bug that we’ll want to fix. Do you mind reporting this in a GitHub issue so that our engineers can look into is?

Comment: @nburk https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/13704

Comment: @nburk same error as https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8832

Answer (score 2):

the only solution we found is to check what is the limit for your query and then use pagination (skip, take) params in loop to download data part by part and glue them back together then ... not optimal, but, it works. See existing bug report for example

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8832